# how to access/modify QObject, how to interoperate between Qt5 and a library

Tags: c++, qt5

I created a command-line program. I now want to add a Qt5 GUI wrapper onto it. (I am very new to Qt5 C++ programming) Previously the program simply displays command-line outputs, now I want it to display outputs on the Qt5 window. (I have converted the core code of the CLI program into a library)

My Qt5 program (a class inheriting QMainWindow) starts my library in a new STD thread. (Is using STD thread correct?) While my library is being executed (and it can take hours), it returns outputs in callback functions. In those callback functions I want to display those outputs in a QTextEdit instance; And so my Qt5 crashes all the time (and the console always says "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"), as this must be the wrong way to modify QObject.

How should I do it? What is the correct way of accessing/modifying QObject instances in a threaded function? (I want to run my library in another thread (under multithreading) because I don't want to freeze my Qt5 window) Do I need to lock a mutex? Perhaps I should use a queue structure and collect any outputs with the queue and read the queue to update my QTextEdit instance within QMainWindow (but now I need a loop function)? I hope, a kind expert can advise me.

Comment: What does it mean to "start a library in a new thread"?

Comment: Qt UI should be modified by a single thread (the same thread running the UI itself). You should used signals and slots to communicate between the different threads.

Comment: Signals and slots? Alright

Comment: My Qt5 program launches a new STD thread to run my code (the library). If I run it in the same thread (i.e. no multithreading), then my Qt5 program will freeze as it waits for the completion of the process of the library.

Comment: signals and slots ...

So, is it still ever possible to access/modify a QObject instance in a running STD thread? Must I lock a mutex?

Answer (score 0):

I myself have found the solution.

1. One must use QThread. I think, STD thread can never access/modify QObject instances?

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html

the important lines:

-initialize:

```
WorkerThread *workerThread = new WorkerThread(this);
connect(workerThread, &WorkerThread::resultReady, this, &MyObject::handleResults);
connect(workerThread, &WorkerThread::finished, workerThread, &QObject::deleteLater);
```

-invoke:

```
workerThread->start();
```

2. The callback functions must be able to see the thread instance and call this "emit" function. This "emit" function is automatically defined in the .moc file. (Notice: the token "emit" is a macro.)

in the documentation page

```
emit resultReady(result);
```

In my case my callback functions call this function with the thread variable.

```
emit workerThread->resultReady(result);
```

So whenever this "resultReady" is called, the "handleResults" function gets called. In my case the "handleResults" function is defined inside my QMainWindow-inheriting "myMainWindow" class.

```
void QMainWindow::handleResults(const QString &s){
// Finally I can access/modify the QTextLine instances  XDDD
}
```

3. One difficulty is, I must use a global variable to pass parameters into my library code whenever I invoke this "workerThread->start();" line.

Thanks anyway. XD